# select closest element - loop to first / traverse table

Tags: jquery

I have a table row of the following structure:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" limit="one"></input></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" limit="one"></input></td>
</tr>
```

I need to find a way to target the next / closest input to the one that has been checked, and give it a .attr("disabled").

The issue I've got is that using closest simply targets the same element, and using next will not target the first element if the element being ticked is already the last one in the row.

Any and all help / nudges in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: It should be `<input />`.

Comment: Do you want both neighbours or just the next one? and if that's not there the prev one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5ys5w/)